# Multiple definitions of "model" and "frame"

Tags: meaning

1) There was a **model** of the new bank in the mayor's office.
Does model here mean a small representation or a structural design?

2) The **frame** for the new building was constructed.
Does frame here mean to plan or to construct? I think of plan and construct as synonyms, but I have to choose one.

There is not much context provided other than the sentence, so I have to make my best guess using the sentence.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have to use (context-specific) default senses. But you haven't given a lot of context here. I'd go with 'small-scale plastic (etc) replica' and 'steel scaffolding'.

Comment: "Model", in this sense, simply means "representation".  Generally it would be a 3-dimensional representation, but not always.  The implication of the second sentence is that the frame has been put together -- ie, wood or metal members fastened together, awaiting the attachment of walls and roof.  But, absent more context, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Either interpretation is possible in the two sentences. There is no way of knowing with certainty. Without additional context, all you can do is guess—as you already have.